# Upgrade uses OnCommit Custom Action from previous installer

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje, vsinstaller

While upgrading my solution from version 1 to 2 using the new MSI, I noticed one of my custom actions which configure the application was using values which belong to version 1 (on the OnCommit action)

I added messageboxes and logs that print out the assembly version and confirmed that during an upgrade, the windows installer is using the dll from the previous MSI. However, if I manually install the newer MSI the correct custom action is used.

Is there a way to get around this? Have not found much information on why it uses the previous custom action?

I set the `RemovePreviousVersions = true` and **UpgradeCodes** are equal while **ProductCodes** are different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is an old bug:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555184

and there is another support article about it that I can't find. It may have been deleted because it applies to older versions of setup projects. I think the detours are things like renaming the assembly, and changing its assembly version.

The issue (as you might guess) is that the uninstall loads the assembly to do the uninstall, and the assembly from the upgrade install is identical as far as the load rules determine in this situation (reflection loading), so it does not load your new assembly but uses the older one that is already loaded. This all implies that you are using a very old version of Visual Studio setup projects that first uninstall the old product then install the new one. That hasn't been the default behavior since (and including) Visual Studio 2008, so I don't think you'd get the issue with a newer version.